# Vue JS How to remove zombie event?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to remove zombie event?

When switching forward and back $on events work out many times.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <input type="button" @click.prevent="click()" value="click">
<template>

<script>
  export default { 
    methods: {
      click: function (){
        this.$emit('go')
      }
    }
  }
<script>
```

Children.vue

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      go: function () {
        console.log('event received')
      }
    },
    created: function (){
        this.$parent.$on('go', this.go);
    }
  }
<script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove the event when you remove the component:

```
<script>
  export default {
    methods: {
      go: function () {
        console.log('event received')
      }
    },
    created: function (){
        this.$parent.$on('go', this.go);
    },
    beforeDestroy: function (){
        this.$parent.$off('go',this.go);
    }
  }
<script>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have `click` method in [created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) lifecycle hook, so it will get called whenever the `children` component will be rendered.